# Why collections.Callable provides __contains__(), __hash__(), __len__() and __call__()

Tags: python, callable

Why does the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html?#collections.Callable) says:

> class collections.Callable
>
> ABCs for classes that provide respectively the methods **contains**(), **hash**(), **len**(), and **call**().

And not only `__call__()` ?

What is the role of `__contains__()`, `__hash__()`, `__len__()` for callable object?

For instance, do I need to make my classes hashable?

Comment: Notice the word *respectively*.

Comment: I'm Tired. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstand what that text says. The documentation covers **four** ABCs:

```
class collections.Container
class collections.Hashable
class collections.Sized
class collections.Callable
```

The [grammar construct *respectively*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24525/what-does-the-word-respectively-mean-in-software-development) in the sentence *ABCs for classes that provide respectively the methods* attaches a separate method to each of the  four classes here, in order.

So `Container` provides `__contains__()`, `Hashable` covers `__hash__()`, `Sized` covers `__len__()` and `Callable` covers `__call__()`.

In other words, `Callable` only provides a `__call__()` method, not any of the other 3 methods.